# How do I use "both" with someone who is a doctor and professor?

Tags: word-usage, word-order, determiners, forms-of-address

I would like to know if a person is a doctor and a professor, how should I address that person in writing?

- “Doctor and Professor”
- “Doctor/Professor”

Can I use “both” to say what their professions are?

- He is both doctor and professor

Comment: If it's _titles_ you are asking about, see [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/125282/is-it-common-to-refer-to-someone-as-prof-dr-lastname)

Answer (score 1):

> He's both a doctor and a professor.

is OK, but

> He's a both doctor and professor.

is an error.
That is, "both" could only be used in a statement, but not a title.